# Сохранение информации в Stringgrid до следующего входа

Tags: delphi, строки

Как сделать так, чтобы информация, введенная в `Stringgrid`, сохранялась впоследствии и после выхода, но могла быть потом в любой момент быть редактирована? Где у как это указать?

Comment: Нигде. Вам нужно ее самостоятельно куда-то сохранить. Например в XML-файл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я к сожалению, с программированием сталкиваюсь впервые. Но так вышло, что пришлось( Правильно  я понимаю, что если я информацию сохраню в файл то при запуске он будет считывать ее и помещать в стринггрид. Смогу ли я ее изменять впоследствии? Не посоветуете статьи по данной теме?

Comment: Нет. При запуске вам нужно будет ее самостоятельно из файла прочитать и заполнить ваш `StringGrid`. Если изменение таблицы в программе разрешено, то да, сможете. Ну или если откроете ваш файл блокнотом :) Насчет статей, начните с чего-нибудь о работе с файлами.

Comment: kot-da-vinci, Благодарю =)

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет типичная связка DB-Aware компонентов, где для хранения данных используется любой DataSet в памяти, к примеру из стандартной поставки TClientDataSet, у него есть методы SaveToFile и LoadFromFile - умеет сохранять в бинарник, или XML.
С TStringGrid так не выйдет. В качестве табличного представления можно использовать стандартный TDBGrid.

Comment: [Пример работы с ClientDataSet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fztvq0GsKyTVd0bU9KUlg4T3c/view?usp=sharing)